# cannot run my app after the update

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated my mac to 10.11.2 as well as android studio to 1.5.1
and I got a problem that I can't run my app, but i am able to run AVD alone

when I tried to run my app I got "waiting for adb"
and

```
cannot run program "/Users/xxxxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=13, Permission denied 
IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=13, Permission denied
```

it was working fine before

thanks

Comment: can you change the permission using chmod

Comment: thanks, but change it to what? what is the right permission?

Comment: Enable your ADB Integration. Check it is enabled or not . Go to Tools --> Android --> set checked in Enable ADB Integration

Comment: Naveen Kumar M , therealprashant  thanks both, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Goto platform-tools --> $cd /Users/xxxxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
2. Then Change the permission of adb --> $chmode 777 adb
3. Restart your Android studio.
4. Done.